# How to get a super short guitar strap?

Tags: amplifiers

I have a roland microcube and I can't find a replacement for it's broken strap. I'm trying to find some kind of a short strap that would be suitable for use with this amp as on the image.

Any idea?

http://guitarfx_ie.s3.amazonaws.com/images/production/276/microcube.jpg?1376079750

Comment: Auto breaker's yard - seat belt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any strap or belt that you would normally use and just cut it down to size. This could be a seat belt, as Tim pointed out, or you could use a normal guitar strap.

Once cut, make sure you seal the end against fraying - many straps just need heat sealing.

Sorting the ends isn't that tricky - you can get the end pieces from various shops that sell parts for amps, and most just clamp on. Some will need a hole cut through the strap, but this can be easily done with a drill.

Comment: you've not tried drilling through webbing (as in seat-belt material), have you !!? A hole punch or hot nail are more successful.

Comment: I've always just used a sharp drill bit (as I've never had a suitable hole punch) - hot nail sounds a good idea though.